# No inserta el opción select de mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Buen día tengo una duda,
tengo un opción `select` el cual esta trayendo registros de mi tabla pero al momento de querer insertar los datos no me inserta nada adjunto `vr_dump($query)`.

```
string(117) "INSERT INTO generales (departamento, periodo, tipo, materia, grupo, nivel) VALUES ('','2020-2','','','','')"
```

Entonces tengo el siguiente código el cual me muestra el opción `select` pero no me manda nada a guardar el `insert`.

```
 <select>
                   <option value="0">Seleccione Nuevo Grupo</option>
                   <?php
                           include("conecta.php");

                    // Realizamos la consulta para extraer los datos
                     $query = $link -> query ("SELECT * FROM generales");
                     while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                    // En esta sección estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
                    echo "<option value={$valores['id']} name='grupo'> {$valores['grupo']} </option>";
                  }
                   ?>
      </select>
```

Comment: Esta sintaxis no es correcta: `echo "<option value={$valores['id']} name='grupo'> {$valores['grupo']} </option>";`, tienes que usar comillas para `value` y para `name`, y las comillas simples no funcionan sin concatenación para tomar valores de array, en comillas dobles puedes omitir las comillas para obtener los datos del array. Intenta así: **`echo "<option value=\"$valores[id]\" name=\"grupo\"> $valores[grupo]} </option>";`**, si todo lo demás está bien en tu código debería funcionar de ese modo. Luego te explico por qué, pues un comentario da para poco...

Comment: pues me imprime esto --string(117) "INSERT INTO generales (departamento, periodo, tipo, materia, grupo, nivel) VALUES ('','2020-2','','','','')"

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($valores);` dentro del bucle y dinos qué muestra. Imagino que hay datos y que todo lo demás está OK: apertura/cierre del `select` y demás cosas. Tampoco se ve el código donde creas ese `INSERT`

Comment: me dice null no me aparece nada

Comment: Entonces lo primero es verificar eso, pues tu consulta `SELECT * FROM generales` no está trayendo datos por algún motivo. Revisa la conexión, revisa la base de datos, revisa que esa tabla existe y tiene datos, etc. Ninguno de esos controles están en tu código. No seas optimista cuando programes, sé lo más pesimista posible, controlando todo lo que puede salir mal.

Comment: nos estás mostrando un INSERT sin datos pero no el código que genera ese insert...